# Как с помощью c# узнать модель шлюза по умолчанию (роутера)

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос в следующем: как программным образом на c# узнать модель шлюза по умолчанию (роутера)? Максимум что я мог узнать, так это его ip-адрес с помощью улиты WMI. Аналогичную процедуру можно было проделать, используя класс NetworkInterface.

P.S: Следует отметить, что винда строит сетевую инфраструктуру, где этот заветный шлюз по умолчанию отображается (фактически можно посмотреть MAC, IP, Серийный номер, модель и т.д)

Comment: копайте в сторону UPnP

Comment: или snmp, если девайс поддерживает этот протокол. WMI в основном для компов.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IPAddress GetDefaultGateway()
{
    var card = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault();
    if(card == null) return null;
    var address = card.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.FirstOrDefault();
    return address.Address;
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634868/get-the-default-gateway)

Comment: этот метод возвращает айпишник шлюза по умолчанию...а я хочу узнать его модель

Comment: Я думаю что это можно сделать через WMI, но не до конца уверен как именно так как в основном это касается информации о ПК (локальном или удаленном) нежели чем вторичном устройстве.